# Elements that are part of state use intitial case of other parts of state (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Elements that are part of state don't use updated values of other parts of state.
Specifically, I have one element that a part of state and one that is not. If I update a state variable (just a counter, say) from the element that is not part of state, it works as expected and increments. If I update it from the element that is part of state, it only ever increments from the initial case, never using the incremented counter.

Sorry if the above is confusing, I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it.
Small example code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const [holder, setHolder] = useState([
    // This only ever sets counter to 1
    <div
      style={{ height: "50px", width: "50px", backgroundColor: "red" }}
      onMouseDown={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}
    />
  ]);
  const nonStateHolder = [
    // This updates counter normally
    <div
      style={{ height: "50px", width: "50px", backgroundColor: "blue" }}
      onMouseDown={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}
    />
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      {holder} {nonStateHolder} {counter}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-firefly-vhsygw?file=/src/App.js

I've figured out some workarounds but they're very hacky. I'd love to understand how to access updated state from within the element that is declared in a useState hook.

Comment: I'm sure there must be a duplicate around - but google "stale closure" in React for enlightenment. The easiest fix is to use a functional state update: `setCount(oldCount => oldCount + 1);`

Comment: Thank you @RobinZigmond, that solved it! I really did look for a duplicate but I sort of lacked the vocab to search it properly. Thanks again!